# Authenticate model issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I have a rails 4 app where I want to have certain books require a secret password to see.

I have a model called Book.rb:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_secure_password :validations => false
end
```

and a sign_in.html.haml that has the form:

```
= form_for login_book_path do |f| 
   = f.password_field :password
   = f.submit "View Book"
```

and the login book path routes to the following controller method:

```
def book_login
  @book = Book.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
  respond_to do |format|
     if @book.authenticate(params[:password])
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
     else
        format.html { render :sign_in }
     end
  end
end
```

If I hardcode the password (like `@book.authenticate("thesecretpassword")`, it correctly redirects me to the root_url. But for some reason, without hardcoding it doesn't work (just sends me back to sign_in.html.haml?

Here's the output in the terminal when I hit the "VIEW BOOK" button:

```
Started POST "/the-wizard-book/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-24 14:04:48   -0700
Processing by BooksController#book_login as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Nx2OkI/FjJwq6zmcT5KLSkQpr9hYa83RL7CFmLQW0/g=", "/the-wizard-book/sign_in"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"View Book", "slug"=>"the-wizard-book"}
Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books"  WHERE "books"."slug" = 'the-wizard-book' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: can you also check that `@book` is also present, and write `if @book && @book.authenticate(params[:password]`

Comment: are you getting value from `params[:slug]`

Comment: @Sontya, Yea, I get the value from params[:slug]

Comment: @book is definitely present as well, I just checked

Comment: form_for is saying`login_book_path` and your method name is `book_login` so how it is working? you have defined `as:` in routes?

Comment: @Sontya, yes I have `as: ` in my routes.rb, I also just posted the terminal output in my question to help more

Comment: are you using rails 4.1 and above

Comment: if yes, have you permitted password field `params.require(:book).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)`